# RTK Query Sending request on Next app Mounting

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to have controll on when RTKQuery sends a request eg if a user clicks submit or search button but on App mount i have obseved the app sends a request How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to trigger a query later in response to a UI event, e.g. when a button is clicked. For this you likely want to use a [Lazy Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery). Instead of running the query when the component mounts it returns a trigger function to be called later when you want to run the query endpoint.

Example:

```
const [queryTrigger, result] = useLazyQuery();

...

const handler = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await queryTrigger(/* arg */).unwrap();
    ...
  } catch(error) {
    ...
  }
};

...

<Button onClick={handler}>
  Click me to manually trigger query
</Button>
```